# Geometry nodes: Select vertex on an edge by angle

Tags: node-editor, vertices, geometry, select

I have a simple mesh, which is just an edge and i want to instance objects on some points.

1. Points, which have 3 or 4 connected edges
2. Points, which have 2 connected edges, but have 90 degree angle between them.

I managed to solve the first problem, but don't really know how to solve the second one.

[image: Initial curve]
[image: Cubes instanced on certain points]
[image: Node Graph]

Comment: pls provide blend file so we don't have to rebuild everything manually. thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's self descriptive:

[image]

But if not, the selection is:

> If the vertex has more than 2 edges, or…
>
> …If the vertex has exactly 2 edges, and the direction from 1st to 2nd
> vertex of **first edge** is at 90° to the direction from 1st to 2nd
> vertex of the **second edge**

[image]