# Geometry nodes: Split curve to segments by angle

Tags: node-editor, bezier-curves, edges, geometry

I have a bunch of connected edges as a base mesh. What I want is to split my edges by angle, convert theses edges to a curve and trim that curve by a certain distance. Split Edges node works, but does not give me the result I want. How can I split edges in the marked areas?
Thanks!

[image]
[image]

Comment: You want to split only the marked areas, or do you want to keep the presented splits as well?

Comment: I cannot tell if the _Split Edges_ node is working, because at the moment it is not responsible for the splits in your example, it is the fact that spline control points can only have a maximum of two connections, so wherever the mesh is branching, the _Mesh to Curve_ node creates separate splines. And you can plug the _Spline Length_ node directly into the _Math_ node, no need for the _Capture Attribute_ there.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann Yep, you are right, after removing theses nodes i still get the same result. Do u know maybe how i can split marked points and keep presented splits as well?

Comment: Split Edges node changed after B3.6. Which version do you use?

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady Blender 3.6.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Blender 3.6.0

After taking my selection setup from your previous [question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/300537/60486), all you need to do is add 7 nodes:

[image]

The algorithm is to delete the selected points, and then on another copy of the geometry, split all edges and merge back only the points not deleted in the other copy (recognized by "Geometry Proximity" - if the distance is greater than $0$ - the point was deleted). Convert back to curve and trim.

### Blender 3.6.2

Theoretically minor [versions](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/299235/60486) shouldn't introduce breaking changes, but apparently here it's the case and it hurts - [to add in salt to injury](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eggcorn), it doesn't automatically convert the old behavior to equivalent nodes in the new version (like it did with e.g. *Transfer Attribute* node). So this is how I implemented the old behavior of *Split Edges* node with all edges selected:

[image]

### Result:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Oh, nice... I didn't find the way to do that. +1

Comment: Thanks a lot for you help!

Comment: They don't half put us through it.. what is the new behaviour of _Split Edges_?  (I'm lazy)

Comment: @RobinBetts I didn't test it thoroughly, it seems it resembles more (or is exactly as) the modeling operator in edit mode. But I think it has been reverted in Blender 4.0 (no reason to try and test, it's alpha, so could be changed again).